# Singleton approach on constructor

Tags: c++, oop, object

I'm attempting to pass an object from one class constructor to another, but, it does not seem to want to work. Here is the code below:

I have the following class:

```
class STFT {

    public:

      template<typename Inverse>
      STFT(Inverse begin, Inverse end, size_t x, size_t y, WindowType type)
      {
          switch(type) 
          {
              case 0: 
              this->w = Window(0, 100, this->w); // "0" is the type of window, 100 is the size, this-w is a reference to the object. 
              break;

              case 1:

              break;
          }         
      }
    protected:
       Window w;
};
```

I have multiple classes `Hamming`, `Hanning` which all inherit from the class `Window` .. What I would like to do is have the constructor in `Window` determine which object to initialise..

```
Window(int theWindow, size_t size, Window& w)
{
   switch(theWindow)
   {
      case 0:
        w = new Barlett(100);
      break;
      //**
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

`no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Barlett*' to 'const Window&'`

I think it's because I cannot convert `Window` to `Barlett` even though `Barlett` is inherited from `Window`.

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be greatful :)

Comment: The problem is that it cannot assign a `Barlett*` to a `Window`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I kind of figured that; is there a solution to this problem? I.e. I need to pass a universal object `Window` that can be assigned to `Barlett` and other objects

Comment: Have you tried `w = Barlett(100);`?

Comment: `Barlett*` is a pointer, and `const Window&` is not.

Comment: why do you pass `w` if you want to create a new object? Why do you try to use a constructor as a factory? This makes zero sense to me.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yeah, it compiles the code, but, it treats it as it's `Window` and not barlett

Comment: You probably need an `std::unique_ptr<Window>`, which you can reset to `new Barlett(100)` or whatever.

Comment: As others have suggested, if you declare a variable as `Window w`, it's never going to be anything other than a `Window`. You're going to need a pointer to get polymorphic behavior, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you're trying to create a factory, but you are doing it in the constructor. That doesn't make sense. Put it somewhere else:

```
class WindowFactory {
    public:
    static Window* create(int theWindow, size_t size)
    {
       Window *w;
       switch(theWindow)
       {
         case 0:
           w = new Barlett(100);
           break;
         //**
       }
       return w;
    }
};

//....
Window *w = WindowFactory::create(0, 10);
```

Note: For the sake of example I added it as static method, but for flexibility and testibility you might want to instantiate a concrete WindowFactory object and call `create` on it.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense and what I was looking for :) Is there no way to do this inside the constructor?

Comment: @Phorce: With this: `this->w = Window(0, 100, this->w);` a constructor doesn't return anything, this is just creating a temporary `Window` object, modifying `this->w` in the process, and the assigning that temporary object to the same `this->w` you just changed. Doing it in the constructor just makes no sense at all. A constructor for `Window` class is going to create `Window` objects. What's more, when you derive `Barlett` from it and create one of those, the `Window` constructor is going to get called again. It's just all wrong.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Thank you for this, I now understand.. I think it's due to the lack of sleep I've had and the time I've spent writing and thinking about this.:)

Comment: @Phorce: No problem, it happens sometimes. When you start to dream about this stuff, it's time to take a break. Still, look on the bright side - since you're modifying `this->w` on both sides of the assignment, you're getting undefined behavior, so it *might* work the way you want...